# She manhandled the posts into place

Tags: meaning, determiners

What is meant by the sentence:

> She manhandled the posts **into place**.

I found it as an example of the usage of the word manhandle at Merriam-Webster website.

I think the sentence should be:

> She manhandled the posts **at their right place**.
>
> or
>
> She manhandled the posts **into their place**.

if it is meant that she moved the posts at some place. I have never heard: something is moved into place.

Comment: [manhandle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/manhandle) *Move (a heavy object) by hand with great effort.* That's from OxfordDictionaries, but you could have looked a few lines further down on the M-W page to find the example *They manhandled the heavy boxes onto the truck.*

Comment: Since you found this example on the Merriam-Webster site, I'm guessing you looked at the definition of manhandle. If you [edit] your question to explain what you didn't understand the definition, we might be able to reopen your question.

Comment: @ColleenV I thought the sentence should be: "She manhandled the posts at their right place.", if it is meant that she moved the posts at some place. I have never heard: something is moved into place.

Comment: @Fumblefingers This question has been updated with more detail if you want to take another look.

Comment: Unless her task was simply to ***lay each post down*** right next to the location where it would subsequently be fixed ***upright*** in the ground (to support a fence, for example), I'd be more likely to use ***into position***. Note [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=move+it+into+place%2Cmove+it+into+position&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmove%20it%20into%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmove%20it%20into%20position%3B%2Cc0) showing that ***move it into position*** is significantly more common than ***move it into place***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> She manhandled the posts into place.

This would be how someone might normally phrase the sentence (manhandle is not a super common word).

"To move  into place" means to cause the thing to be in the correct place. (*into* is similar to *in* but always implies motion rather than location).

> She manhandled the posts at their right place.

The definition of manhandled cited above indicates motion with great effort, so this sentence would imply she moved the posts but the posts didn't change position, which seems rather odd. The sentence in any case doesn't sound natural.

Comment: So it appears that this meaning is derived from idioms: fall into place, put something into place.  I tried to google, but I didn't find an idiom: "to move into place", which suggests this meaning.

Comment: Should this statement be rephrased as "She manhandled the posts into their place."?

Comment: "into place" vs "into their place" won't really make a difference; either would be reasonable. Likewise, move into place isn't really derived from idioms, certainly not strictly understood. "into" is used with motion, so can be used with various verbs indicating motion (to move, to place, to put).

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "to move into place" is correct, idiomatic and common. As a 
[random example](http://gizmodo.com/chernobyls-gigantic-radiation-shield-is-now-being-moved-1788967188) from the first page of google "A giant metal shield [...] at Chernoby [...] is being moved into place."

Manhandle means move by hand. And so "manhandle into place" is correct and idiomatic. You could use other verbs that imply movement: "push into place", "heave into place"

Saying "move at their right place" is correct English, but means something different: The posts are moved, while staying in one location. (they could be rotated, for example). Correct English, but probably not what you would usually want to mean.

Comment: Reason for downvote?